# Subsets which contain the unit and are closed under inverses

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In the group theory literature, is there a name for subsets of groups which contain the unit and are closed under inverses (but not necessarily closed under multiplication)? Where can I read about them? If you don't have a reference in mind, can you please list a few noteworthy properties of such sets?

In particular, I am interested in the case where the group is finite.

Example: if $G$ is a group and $A\subset G$, then $AA^{-1}$ is such a subset. In fact, this is what made me pay attention to these kinds of subsets; I was working on a problem where I had to use these.

Comment: Search this site on $AA^{-1}$ (https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=[group-theory]AA^{-1}) and you will find some interesting results. The sets you are referring to do not have a special name, as far as I know.

Comment: Well, in Universal Algebra, if we disregard certain operations from an algebraic structure, we talk about a *reduct* of that, and a subalgebra of a reduct is called *subreduct*.